# VBA Macro not pasting correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I created a VB macro that combines data from 2 sheets into a single sheet so that it can be printed and given out as an overview of the projects we are working on.

What it should (And did in the past) is to go to Sheet 1, copy all the data from A3 to R of the last row that had data in column A.

It then pastes that data starting in A3 of the combined worksheets.

Then it copies the data the same way from Worksheet 2 and pastes it after the last used row in the combined worksheet.

I made some adjustments recently and now the macro doesn't seem to be working.

It pastes the first worksheet correctly (Lean Projects), but the second worksheet's data (Kaizen) isn't copying correctly.

Instead of copying all the data down to the final input row, it copies all the data starting after the number of rows in the first worksheet. (Example: if there are 24 entries in worksheet 1, worksheet 2 is beginning to copy at row 25.

```
Sub CreateCombinedSheet()

'Assign the worksheets to their respective variables
Set wsCombined = Sheets("Combined (View)(Macro)")
Set wsProjects = Sheets("Lean Projects (View)")
Set wsKaizen = Sheets("Kaizen (View)")

'Clear the Combined worksheet before repopulating it if there is data present

'If the first cell of data, A3, is not empty
If wsCombined.Range("A3") <> "" Then

    'Then clear all rows after row 3 until the last row
    wsCombined.Range("A3", wsCombined.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Address).EntireRow.Delete

End If

'Copy all the data in the Lean Projects worksheet
wsProjects.Range("A3", wsProjects.Range("R3").End(xlDown).Address).Copy

'Paste the Lean Projects data into the Combined worksheet
wsCombined.Range("A3").PasteSpecial

'Copy all the data in the Kaizen worksheet
wsKaizen.Range("A3", wsKaizen.Range("R3").End(xlDown).Address).Copy

'Paste the Kaizen data into the Combined worksheet starting in the row after the currently last used row

wsCombined.Range("A" & wsCombined.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

If anyone can tell where I went wrong, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks,

Example: [image]

Update 11/18:

I commented out the Second Paste function so I could see for myself exactly what was being copied. I found that it is copying the correct data from the second worksheet. The issue comes when I paste that data after the last row in the combined worksheet (After the first sheet's data ends). When I manually past there, I see all the second sheet data as it should be. Then a second later, it appears to collapse upward and Im left with the data starting at row 25 of the second sheet to the last row (28) then the formula on sheet 2 is extrapolated further up to row 50 on the combined sheet.

Comment: Have you defined any of your variables with `Dim`?

Comment: I used "Set" it was working fine by doing that. Do I need to use Dim Instead?

Comment: Sometimes that can correct issues.  `Dim wsCombined, wsProjects, wsKaizen, wsSheet As Sheet` then remove all `Set` (those are separate lines)

Comment: I tried to set them with Dim like the 'Dim wsCombined as Worksheet wsComined = Sheets("Combined (View)(Macro)")' This gives me a Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: The `Dim wsCombined As Worksheet` needs to be a separate line from `wsCombined = blah`

Comment: Just ran this macro on a test page and I could not duplicate the error.

Comment: Yeah I made it 2 lines. The first line being Dim wsCombined as Worksheet. and then the second line defining it using wsCombined = "Sheets("Combined (View)(Macro)"). It didn't like me doing that. I think the way I'm defining it when using Dim needs to be different somehow

Comment: Can you post samples of the two worksheets? (With proprietary data removed?)

Comment: Im attempting to do that now. Trying to figure out how to load a scrubbed version in

Comment: You might have 'ghost' lines that `.End(xlDown)` thinks are rows. Try deleting all the blank lines after the data in your second spreadsheet

Comment: I ensured all lines were empty. And I just found something else. I commented out the second paste line at the end of the subroutine so that it would copy 1, paste 1, copy 2 and I could paste what it was copying in another location to make sure it was copying correctly. If I paste it in a new sheet, all 28 rows come out fine. If I copy it right after the data in the combined sheet, i see all 28 rows populate, then a second later it all collapses and I get row 25-28 and an extrapolated row 29-50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `xlPasteValues` after each of your `.PasteSpecial` code lines

```
wsCombined.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

And

```
wsCombined.Range("A" & wsCombined.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Actually was just about to update on that front. the issue seems to stem from the pasting of conditional formatting. If I add "Paste:=xlPasteValues" then the macro works fine. If I just leave it as is or add in "Paste:=xlAllMergingConditionalFormats", then it goes back to doing the odd things described above. How do I get it to keep the Conditional Formatting without all the mess that it's doing now?

Comment: You could set the conditional formatting on the new sheet in your macro.  I believe that conditional formatting is tied to a specific range or cell in a given sheet.

Comment: Ok I found a work around. I set the conditional formatting on the columns in the combined worksheet since the conditional formatting should be the same and shouldn't be going anywhere. Then I set both pastes to be just values. This gives me just the data (So I don't get any weird pastes) and the formatting already on the worksheet colors the data appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Corrections (in my opinion)

```
If wsCombined.Range("A3") > 0 Then
```

Should become

```
IF wsCombined.Range("A3").Value <> "" Then
```

Don't use a custom function for the End function. It's redundant, and limits what you can do with it.

```
wsCombined.Rows("3:" & LastRow(wsCombined)).ClearContents
```

Should become

```
wsCombined.Range("A3",WSCombined.Range("A1048576").End(xlup).Address).EntireRow.Delete
```

Another

```
wsProjects.Range("A3:" & "R" & LastRow(wsProjects)).Copy
```

Should become

```
wsProjects.Range("A3",wSProject.Range("R3").End(xlDown).Address).Copy
```

And so and so forth. I will circle back to this answer shortly, but I would imagine that if you remove your custom function and use the built in functionality for this, the error will go away.

Comment: I made those correction but it's still coming back to the same issue. It copies and paste's the first section right. But then the second worksheet doesn't get copied/pasted correctly into the combined sheet

Comment: wsCombined.Range("A" & (LastRow(wsCombined) + 1)).PasteSpecial
< Did you change this line?

Comment: Ah, no I forgot to modify that line. Im trying to figure out the syntax to change that now. It would be something like wsCombined.Range(wsCombined.End(xlDown.Address) + 1).PasteSpecial. I know that's incorrect, I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure that. It needs to begin pasting the row after the last row used

Comment: `wsCombined.Range("A" & wsCombined.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Thanks. I updated that line and I'm still getting the same issue. Im trying to figure out how to upload the file in question.